# Unable to connect a Custom NSView to its view controller outlet (KPCTabsControl)

Tags: swift, cocoa, viewcontroller, nsview, iboutlet

I am trying to assign a [KPCTabsControl](https://github.com/onekiloparsec/KPCTabsControl) class to a custom NSView. The window view class is MainViewController.

The MainViewController code looks like this:

```
class MainViewController : NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myTabsController: TabsController!
    @IBOutlet var myButton: NSButton!

    //...
}
```

The TabsController code looks like this:

```
class TabsController : NSViewController, KPCTabsControlDataSource, KPCTabsControlDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tabsBar: KPCTabsControl?

    var titles: Array<String> = []

    func tabsControlNumberOfTabs(tabControl: KPCTabsControl) -> UInt {
        return UInt(titles.count)
    }

    //...
}
```

The form looks like this:
[image: Form with custom views]

I tried to connect the "Main View Controller" to the "KPCTabsControl" custom view with control-drag. I get the outlet choices: sourceItemView and view. On the other hand, if I try to connect "Main View Controller" to the "+" button, I get the outlet choices: myButton, sourceItemView and view. I don't understand why the "myTabsController" never appears while the "myButton" outlet is available.

Right now, the custom class of the "KPCTabsControl" view is "KPCTabsControl", I tried to enter "TabsController" but it is not listed in the possible choices. And writing it does not work, the value seems rejected and returns automatically to "KPCTabsControl".

What am I missing?

(I'm using Xcode 7.3.1)

Comment: You're missing the TabsController.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, but what do you mean exactly? The code for TabsController is there and I would like to connect it to the "KPCTabsController" NSView. Like I said, I was unable to define it as a custom class (even if it's a subclass of NSViewController!). And even listed as a `@IBOutlet` and it does not appear as a selectable outlet. I don't understand what is missing.

Comment: There is no TabsController in the xib.

Comment: @Willeke It's a storyboard, but I'm assuming it is similar. So if it's missing, how do I add it?

Comment: I don't use storyboards. Maybe somebody else can tell how to add a view controller to a storyboard.